# Least expensive way to set image for a ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I need to change images in quick(in milliseconds) intervals for my game. I use ImageViews and setImageResource() to set images to the ImageViews. Below is the log with the duration the action took to perform.

1. 10ms     - Pattern4
2. 10ms     - Pattern4
3. 4ms  - Pattern4
4. 6ms  - Pattern4
5. 172ms    - Pattern3
6. 186ms    - Pattern1
7. 174ms    - Pattern2
8. 84ms     - Pattern1
9. 45ms     - Pattern2
10. 196ms    - Pattern3
11. 9ms  - Pattern3
12. 4ms  - Pattern2
13. 70ms     - Pattern1
14. 0ms  - Pattern1
15. 2ms  - Pattern3
16. 40ms     - Pattern2

code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        buttons[i].setImageResource(current_set[i + 2]);
        buttons[i].setTag(current_set[i + 2]);
        buttons[i].requestLayout();
    }
```

The duration mentioned above are the time consumed by 16 method calls which does same action(to set images for 9 ImageViews).

1. Why the same set of 9 pictures in a pattern takes totally different duration to do setImageResource() 9 times(per method call)?
2. Could you please suggest other techniques to reduce the time consumption happens by "setImagResource()"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are writing a game, why are you using `ImageView` in the first place?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,
The concept is so simple as interacting to the buttons in the screen. And also I have no experience in using openGL or anyother similar things. So I decided to just go with the usual ImageViews in a table Layout.
And I believe, if I can overcome this duration issue and make the images getting replaced smoothly in a uniform manner, game will be OK to play.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could save time by getting rid of the `requestLayout()` calls. Beyond that, nobody on the planet has any idea what "Pattern1" is, what the time for "Pattern1" means compared to the time for "Pattern2", what "16 method calls" you are talking about, what those "16 method calls" have to do with any of the times, what the "same action" has to do with any of the times, what "9 pictures in a pattern" means, what is different about "9 pictures in a pattern" compared to "setImageResource() 9 times(per method call)", etc.

Comment: In general, if you want to determine where you are spending your time, use Traceview.

Comment: Sorry CommonsWare for not being clear. I just wanted to keep the question simple.
1. The game has 9 ImageViews.
2. They will get repopulated with different sets of images every second.
3. This happens for 16 times (or 16 seconds) and the issue I face here is the duration taken to repopulate goes up to 190ms that eats the duration given to the players(1000 ms).

Or in basic words, "I am looking for a technique to populate ImageViews in least duration possible"

Thank you for suggesting TraceView :)

Comment: I strongly suspect that you find that your time is coming from excessive (and unnecessary) `requestLayout()` calls.

Comment: I’m not sure, but maybe using bitmap caching will help

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare :) 
I misunderstood that I need requestlayout() to refresh the ImageViews. After removing that I could find the time consumption reduced by about 20%. Thank you :)

Thank you Dexter. I will look to cache images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your images to a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html), set this drawable for your buttons, then use setLevel() to set image for button,so don't need requestLayout().

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        buttons[i].setImageLevel(current_set[i + 2]); // current_set now store image level
        buttons[i].setTag(current_set[i + 2]);
        //buttons[i].requestLayout();
    }
```